# How to crop a raster and change its cell size and extent to match template raster?

Tags: r

I have a set of bioclimatic rasters that I'd like to crop and change to match my template raster.
This means changing projection, cellsize (the template raster has a bigger cellsize) extent and NA cells so that each non-NA cell on the template raster has matching cell on the bioclimatic rasters.

I don't want to change any cell values (except for the necessary changes in upscaling cell size).

Can anyone suggest a workflow in R? I looked through the "raster" package but was unable to figure out a workflow of which I was 100% sure

Comment: could you provide reproducible examples?

Comment: @bird I have no code at all, so sadly I can't give a real or reproducible example

Comment: it is usually very hard to get help here without reproducible (data/code) examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is the `resample()` function in the `raster` package.  Here is a reproducible example of the workflow to do this task.  This first code chunk is mostly to set up the data for reproducibility and to get the specific scenario you are asking about:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(raster)
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(spData)

##Getting Example Datasets##
data("land")
data("us_states")

##Converting the Elevation layer in the "land" dataset to a rasterLayer##
Elev<-raster(xmx=180, xmn=-180, ymx=90, ymn=-90, t(land$elevation), crs=crs("+init=epsg:4326"))

##Looking at the dataset##
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(Elev)+
  tm_raster(palette = terrain.colors(10))+
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)

##Getting necessary projections for spatial transformations##
WGS84<-CRS("+init=epsg:4326")#World Geographical System of 1984
ORLAMB<-CRS("+init=epsg:2992")#Oregon Statewide Lambert Projection

##Creating a fake raster for the US state of Oregon##
OR<-as_Spatial(us_states[us_states$NAME=="Oregon",])
OR_sp<-spTransform(OR, CRSobj=WGS84)
OR_lamb<-spTransform(OR, CRSobj=ORLAMB)
EXT<-extent(OR_lamb)
OR_blank<-raster(EXT, resolution=c(3000,3000), crs=ORLAMB)
values(OR_blank)<-runif(369238, 100, 200)
```

Now we have the specific scenario you are after we have a big world wide elevation data set projected in to WGS84, and a finer resolution fake raster for the US state of Oregon.  The below portion is the main part of the workflow you are asking about

```
OR_ELEV_tmp<-crop(Elev, OR_sp) #Crop the worldwide elevation data to the state of ORegon
ORELEVLAMB<-projectRaster(OR_ELEV_tmp, crs=ORLAMB)#Project into Oregon Statewide Lambert
ELEV_rsmpld<-mask(resample(ORELEVLAMB, OR_blank),OR_lamb)#Resample to the resolution of our fake Oregon raster and mask to the shape of the state

##View the final output
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(ELEV_rsmpld)+
  tm_raster(palette = terrain.colors(10))+
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Just one question: does this work with raster files with no CRS? i've been doing it without an assigned CRS and it seems to be working, but there might be something I'm missing

Comment: Hi @Spectron, Your raster files likely already have a projection defined which you can check with `crs(RASTER)`  If your raster files do not have a projection defined but somehow their extents overlap, you will get a result that is likely wrong.  In the example I gave you, I made a blank fake raster of Oregon, so I had to define the CRS.  The "land" dataset is in the `stars` format, so I converted it to raster, and defined the projection as WGS84, just to be 100% sure I was getting the correct result.  If you read directly using `raster()` these steps are unnecessary.